# CSS selector first-child does not work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have tried to use :nth-child(n), which does not work as well, am I using this selector on the wrong elements?
on the element div with the following class, block_photo.

```
.block_photo:first-child, .block_video:first-child {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

http://tmptstdays4god.ucoz.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html markup is the following:

```
<section class="new photos">
    <h4 class="title">...</h4>
    <div class="block-photo">...</div>
    <div class="block-photo">...</div>
    ...
</section>
```

#### first-child / nth-child

*Matches an element if it is the first child.*

```
.block_photo:first-child {
    /* styles here apply to the .block_photo IF it is the first child */
}
```

In your case, because the first child is `<h4>`, the selector `.block_photo:first-child` matches no element.

#### first-of-type / nth-of-type

*Matches the first element of a certain type*

```
.block_photo:first-of-type {
    /* styles here apply for the first .block_photo element */

    /* that is what you need */
}
```

---

*References:*

[W3C specification on first-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo)
[W3C specification on first-of-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo)

Comment: Thank you! Makes a lot more sense.

Comment: or create a parent element to house these containers .photo_block

Comment: You have also the `first-of-type` solution, see edit.